# Не работает wifi на windows после удаления linux mint

Tags: linux, windows, железо, драйвер

Решил поставить LMDE(Linux mint debian edition) на ноутбук рядом с виндой, но mint не видел wifi.Пробовал поставить драйвер на Линуксе, но не вышло. Я удалил загрузчик grub и в винде отформатировал часть диска с Linux, теперь винда тоже не видит wifi, перестановка драйвера не помогает. Помогите, пожалуйста, я в отчаянии

Answer (score 1):

Прежде всего мы имеем ситуацию при которой на компьютере с Windows не работает Wi-Fi. Я бы рекомендовал проделать следующие шаги для устранения возникшей ситуации:

1. В Windows (10/11) может быть активен режим "в самолёте". Необходимо
   отключить его в меню "Параметры", меню настройки сетей или в центре уведомлений
2. Проверить параметры подключаемого оборудования в UEFI/BIOS. Во время
   настроек приоритета загрузки Windows Bootloader и GRUB в UEFI/BIOS,
   которые Вы, возможно, производили, могло получиться так, что Вы
   случайно отключили Wi-Fi модуль. Наличие такой опции может быть в
   UEFI
3. Убедиться в том, активно ли меню беспроводных соединений. Далее
   перейти в "Диспетчер устройств" и выполнить осмотр компонентов ПК.
   Среди компонентов должен отображаться модуль Wi-Fi или
   неопознанной устройство. Если отображается неопознанное устройство,
   необходимо открыть его свойства и проверить сведения. Поиск ошибки,
   отображаемой там, поможет найти решение
4. Если у Вас ноутбук, возможно, что на нем есть функциональные клавиши
   для быстрых действий (смена яркости, громкости и т.п.). Среди таких
   может быть кнопка отключения Wi-Fi. Вы могли нажать её при попытке войти в UEFI/BIOS или Boot Menu
5. Не исключен вариант поломки модуля, который совпал с Вашими
   экспериментами с ОС